# Protobuf: how to use existing case classes

Tags: scala, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

There are case classes which are already used in the project.
These classes are used in the slick-mapping too. And these classes extends some additional traits.

I don't want to generate all these classes from `*.proto` description.

Is there an opportunity to extend them in `protobuf`?
Or should I use a wrappers for them. And these wrappers will be described in `*.proto` and generated from it.

Comment: I see [tag:scala] - have you tried https://github.com/btlines/pbdirect ?

Comment: Personally, I do not like to mix layers, so I would keep separate case classes for Slick and Protobufs. And convert one into the other with https://scalalandio.github.io/chimney/ (disclaimer: I helped creating this library).

Comment: Case class inheritance is deprecated. I think inheriting non-case-classes from case classes still isn't, but that doesn't make it a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For proto definition

```
message PBPerson {
  int64 id = 1;
  string name = 2;
  google.protobuf.StringValue phone = 3;
  repeated string hobbies = 4;
}
```

and scala case class definition

```
case class Person(
  id: Long,
  name: String,
  phone: Option[String],
  hobbies: Seq[String])
```

you can use https://github.com/changvvb/scala-protobuf-java

```
import pbconverts.{ Protoable, Scalable }
val convertedPBPerson:PBPerson = Protoable[Person,PBPerson].toProto(person)
val convertedPerson:Person = Scalable[Person,PBPerson].toScala(pbPerson)
```

Additionally, this lib uses scala macro to ensure it's a **type-safe** conversion.